# JavaFX WebView - adding new stylesheet rules from a String

Tags: css, javafx, webview

Suppose I have a `String` containing a CSS rule, for example

```
String rule = "body {  background-color: lightblue; }"
```

How do I add this rule to my JavaFX `WebView` / `WebEngine`?

Comment: Note you can execute arbitrary scripts with [`WebEngine#executeScript(String)`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#executeScript(java.lang.String)).

Comment: You could write this to a file and use the url for this file as [`userStyleSheetLocation`](https://openjfx.io/javadoc/13/javafx.web/javafx/scene/web/WebEngine.html#userStyleSheetLocationProperty); depending on the website you want to apply this on you may need to use `!important`...